# GoogleMaps v2 for Android: Cannot remove marker while map is being rendered

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a fragment with:

- GoogleMap v2 fragment
- A "places" button to add markers (user's places)
- A "remove places" button (remove user generated markers)
- Additional markers (such as general point of interests)
- Custom tile overlay

When user clicks on "places" button, the app stores a hashmap with references to markers and places object in a WeakHashMap. When user clicks "remove places" the app iterates over the map  keys calling marker.remove().

When the map is completely rendered, the markers are removed properly, but, if the button is pressed while map is being rendered, then the markers are not removed.

Anyone has experienced the same problem?
How to solve it?

**I cannot use map.clear()** since it removes all markers, polylines, overlays, etc. I just want to remove a previously stored list of markers (user's places) not everything.

Comment: why not use `clear()` https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#clear()

Comment: I have a custom tile provider that is removed when using clear(). Additionally, I have two lists of markers that represent different things and I only want to remove one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the object to store the relation between the Marker and the Place object shouldn't be a WeakHashMap but a HashMap. It solved the problem.

Comment: Too bad this information was not available in your original question :) Congrats for solving it though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a few booleans to check if the map has finished loading. If not delay the removing of the markers until it is. Here's an example:

```
private boolean mLoadFinished, mDelayRemove;

public void removeMarkers() {
    for (Marker marker : markers) {
        marker.remove();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    Button button;
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!mLoadFinished) {
                mDelayRemove = true;
            } else {
                removeMarkers();
            }
        }
    });

    mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {
            mLoadFinished = true;
            if (mDelayRemove) {
                mDelayRemove = false;
                removeMarkers();
            }
        }
    });

    ...
}
```

Comment: Make sense, but, where to set mLoadFinished to false?

Comment: @SimpleLiving basically you don't have to. The only time the map will be rendered is when the Activity is created. And the mLoadFinished variable will be defaulted to false then.

Comment: When I move the map, then I can see gray tiles that are being filled. Is not that "rendering"? or is it only tile display? Because, the problem is that I cannot remove markers when I move the map, or zoom and some tiles are in grey.

Comment: @SimpleLiving you can't detect when the tile downloading has been completed as it's based on the users network. Furthermore markers aren't added at that time, therefore you can't remove them. I don't think you even want to be able to remove markers that aren't visible. How would user know what he removed?

Comment: The problem is that markers were not removed when clicking in "remove button" and the map was downloading tiles (e.g. due to a zoom or move in the map). I've finally solved my problem, but there was not enough info in the description to solve it. See my answer in a couple of minutes. BTW, your answer was good for the question as it was described and therefore I've upvoted it

Answer (score 1):

GoogleMAp.clear() will remove all the marker you plotted on the map

Comment: As stated in the comment, I cannot use googleMap.clear() since it additionally removes overlays, polylines, etc. I will add this to the question's description.